# Laravel 6 | Undefined property: Illuminate\Notifications\ChannelManager::$container

Tags: php, laravel, notifications

Recently I've upgraded Laravel from 5.8 to 6.0 and made some adjusts to make it running smoothly.

In my local environment, it works fine. But when I publish in my server, when I try to send some notifications (mail and broadcast) I receive the following error:

```
ErrorException: Undefined property: Illuminate\Notifications\ChannelManager::$container in /var/www/vialoc_api/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Notifications/ChannelManager.php:53
Stack trace:

#0 /var/www/vialoc_api/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Notifications/ChannelManager.php(53): Illuminate\Foundation\Bootstrap\HandleExceptions->handleError(8, 'Undefined prope...', '/var/www/vialoc...', 53, Array)
#1 /var/www/vialoc_api/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Notifications/SendQueuedNotifications.php(73): Illuminate\Notifications\ChannelManager->sendNow(Object(App\Models\User), Object(App\Notifications\UserConfirmationNotification), Array)
#2 [internal function]: Illuminate\Notifications\SendQueuedNotifications->handle(Object(Illuminate\Notifications\ChannelManager))
#3 /var/www/vialoc_api/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/BoundMethod.php(32): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#4 /var/www/vialoc_api/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/BoundMethod.php(90): Illuminate\Container\BoundMethod::Illuminate\Container\{closure}()
#5 /var/www/vialoc_api/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/BoundMethod.php(34): Illuminate\Container\BoundMethod::callBoundMethod(Object(Illuminate\Foundation\Application), Array, Object(Closure))
#6 /var/www/vialoc_api/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(580): Illuminate\Container\BoundMethod::call(Object(Illuminate\Foundation\Application), Array, Array, NULL)
#7 /var/www/vialoc_api/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Bus/Dispatcher.php(94): Illuminate\Container\Container->call(Array)
#8 /var/www/vialoc_api/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(130): Illuminate\Bus\Dispatcher->Illuminate\Bus\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Notifications\SendQueuedNotifications))
#9 /var/www/vialoc_api/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(105): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Notifications\SendQueuedNotifications))
#10 /var/www/vialoc_api/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Bus/Dispatcher.php(98): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->then(Object(Closure))
#11 /var/www/vialoc_api/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Queue/CallQueuedHandler.php(83): Illuminate\Bus\Dispatcher->dispatchNow(Object(Illuminate\Notifications\SendQueuedNotifications), false)
#12 /var/www/vialoc_api/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(130): Illuminate\Queue\CallQueuedHandler->Illuminate\Queue\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Notifications\SendQueuedNotifications))
#13 /var/www/vialoc_api/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(105): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Notifications\SendQueuedNotifications))
#14 /var/www/vialoc_api/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Queue/CallQueuedHandler.php(85): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->then(Object(Closure))
#15 /var/www/vialoc_api/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Queue/CallQueuedHandler.php(59): Illuminate\Queue\CallQueuedHandler->dispatchThroughMiddleware(Object(Illuminate\Queue\Jobs\RedisJob), Object(Illuminate\Notifications\SendQueuedNotifications))
#16 /var/www/vialoc_api/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Queue/Jobs/Job.php(88): Illuminate\Queue\CallQueuedHandler->call(Object(Illuminate\Queue\Jobs\RedisJob), Array)
#17 /var/www/vialoc_api/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Queue/Worker.php(327): Illuminate\Queue\Jobs\Job->fire()
#18 /var/www/vialoc_api/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Queue/Worker.php(277): Illuminate\Queue\Worker->process('redis', Object(Illuminate\Queue\Jobs\RedisJob), Object(Illuminate\Queue\WorkerOptions))
#19 /var/www/vialoc_api/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Queue/Worker.php(118): Illuminate\Queue\Worker->runJob(Object(Illuminate\Queue\Jobs\RedisJob), 'redis', Object(Illuminate\Queue\WorkerOptions))
#20 /var/www/vialoc_api/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Queue/Console/WorkCommand.php(102): Illuminate\Queue\Worker->daemon('redis', 'vialoc-api,defa...', Object(Illuminate\Queue\WorkerOptions))
#21 /var/www/vialoc_api/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Queue/Console/WorkCommand.php(86): Illuminate\Queue\Console\WorkCommand->runWorker('redis', 'vialoc-api,defa...')
#22 [internal function]: Illuminate\Queue\Console\WorkCommand->handle()
#23 /var/www/vialoc_api/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/BoundMethod.php(32): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#24 /var/www/vialoc_api/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/BoundMethod.php(90): Illuminate\Container\BoundMethod::Illuminate\Container\{closure}()
#25 /var/www/vialoc_api/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/BoundMethod.php(34): Illuminate\Container\BoundMethod::callBoundMethod(Object(Illuminate\Foundation\Application), Array, Object(Closure))
#26 /var/www/vialoc_api/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(580): Illuminate\Container\BoundMethod::call(Object(Illuminate\Foundation\Application), Array, Array, NULL)
#27 /var/www/vialoc_api/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Console/Command.php(183): Illuminate\Container\Container->call(Array)
#28 /var/www/vialoc_api/vendor/symfony/console/Command/Command.php(255): Illuminate\Console\Command->execute(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Illuminate\Console\OutputStyle))
#29 /var/www/vialoc_api/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Console/Command.php(170): Symfony\Component\Console\Command\Command->run(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Illuminate\Console\OutputStyle))
#30 /var/www/vialoc_api/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php(908): Illuminate\Console\Command->run(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
#31 /var/www/vialoc_api/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php(269): Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRunCommand(Object(Illuminate\Queue\Console\WorkCommand), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
#32 /var/www/vialoc_api/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php(145): Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRun(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
#33 /var/www/vialoc_api/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Console/Application.php(90): Symfony\Component\Console\Application->run(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
#34 /var/www/vialoc_api/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Console/Kernel.php(122): Illuminate\Console\Application->run(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
#35 /var/www/vialoc_api/artisan(37): Illuminate\Foundation\Console\Kernel->handle(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
#36 {main}
```

And one note: To upgrade to Laravel 6 on my server, I needed to upgrade to PHP 7.2. I've done this and I think there is some PHP module missing. But I'm stuck to resolve this issue.

To notifications, I'm using Redis for Queue. And I've tried to sent the emails through mailtrap and mailgun, but the response is the same.

Please someone can help me? Tks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've discovered the problem.

My queue was being managed by a supervisor process. And with the upgrade and the code change, the process didn't update the code being processed.

When I ran the following command:

```
sudo supervisorctl restart all
```

Everything starts working again.

Answer (score 0):

Running `composer install` on your server should list any missing modules.

Comment: I did it again. It doesn't show errors for missing modules, just show suggestions. I installed some of them, but the error continues.